# How the parameter of the callback function in useSelector hook knows the state of the redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am studying redux. I came across with useSelector hook that takes a callback function. The parameter of the callback function is the state of the store. My question here is how simply importing useSelector hook from react-redux enables the parameter of the callback function equivalent to the state of the store? Where is the connection between that parameter and the store?

Example

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = () => {
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter)
  return <div>{counter}</div>
}
```

Comment: I looked at the source code and seems that the useSelector hook gets the store making use of another hook useReduxContext it then returns the state selected by the function passed to the useSelector. Here you can take a look: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/hooks/useSelector.ts

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out yourself, react-redux relies on the context provider/consumer pattern provided by react itself. react-redux probably assumes that there is a specific context provider somewhere higher up in the component tree. So the connection between the state parameter and the store is made based on a name convention: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/Context.ts#L20